# mongodb mongorestore assertion failure

Tags: mongodb, mongorestore, database

I've mongodb version 1.8.2 running on production, for which a cron job runs for database dump. I've just upgraded my ubuntu to 12.04. Now I m unable to restore any database/collection. 
It's giving

db.system.indexes Assertion failure _filename.empty() util/mmap.cpp 167

I googled for it, but can't find any suitable answer.

Comment: Did you also upgrade mongodb? What version do you have now?

Comment: I've tried this thing with mongo 2.2.0 as well as 1.8.2.
2.2.0 gives out of disk space while creating system.indexes
while 1.8.2 gives this error

Comment: What is the exact error that 2.2.0 gives? How are running mongodump - can you update the ticket with the command syntax? 1.8.2 is very old and I'd recommend using 2.0.7 or 2.2.0. Can you also append `df -h` to the question?

Answer (score 2):

Try setting `ulimit -n 64000` in the startup script, usually, `/etc/init.d/mongodb`. This worked for me.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mongodb-user/RNwc6j6oiSg/PspURcJUxMIJ